# Delphi XE2: how to define not members of a class functions in the component unit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have problem with not members of a class functions. I want to use that functions in a new component unit but they did not work in a component unit!

these two functions must assign to another function in a dll as parameter.

When I used this 2 functions(not members of class) in main form they can work but in the new component unit, the dll function cannot call back these two functions any more! How can I resolve this problem ? Is this delphi bug ? because I am using Delphi XE Update 2 this is lastest version of delphi maybe it is a bug!

```
  TComp12 = class(TCustomPanel)
  private
  ....
  protected
  ....
  public
  ....
  end;

  function function1(opaque: Pointer; plane: Pointer): Pointer; cdecl;
  function function2(opaque: Pointer; picture: Pointer; plane: Pointer) : Pointer; cdecl;

procedure Register;

implementation


procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Comp1', [TComp12]);
end;

function function1(opaque: Pointer; plane: Pointer): Pointer; cdecl;
begin
......
end;
function function2(opaque: Pointer; picture: Pointer; plane: Pointer) : Pointer; cdecl;
begin
......
end;
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Could you add some more code to show how you are trying to use these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your code, and it is not a bug in Delphi.

There is a bug in the following code:

```
function VLCLock(opaque: Pointer; plane: Pointer): Pointer; cdecl;
var
  ctx: TCTX;
begin
  ctx := TCTX(opaque);
  Pointer(plane^) := @(ctx.FBuffer.StartLine[0]);
  Result := nil;
end;
```

`TCTX(opaque)` should be `TCTX(opaque^)`. You must fix all similar occurrences in your code.

Comment: Owww thanks Marcus :) but why the code can work in main form directly and why don't work in the component class! Anyway I will try it thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear what your question is, but I'm guessing:

1) perhaps you wrote some code in an older version of Delphi (your tags suggest perhaps even something ancient, like Delphi 7)

2) Your code is using "function pointers"

3) Your code might be trying to mix'n'match function pointers for free-standing functions (like function1 and function2, for example) with class method pointers.

If so, you can't do that :)

Here's a good link on Delphi function pointers.  It should be 100% applicable to Delphi XE2:

http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/pointers.htm

Comment: thank for your reply but my problem is not with pointers looket this cpp file please http://sally-project.googlecode.com/svn-history/r551/trunk/sallyPlugins/plugins/MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.cpp this file has 3 static methods "lockResource", "unlockResource" and "displayResource" this 3 methods setting to another function as parameter in RenderFile function, from here "libvlc_video_set_callbacks(m_pMediaPlayer, lockResource, unlockResource, displayResource, &m_Context);"  there is no pointer you have to set directly static method to in libvlc_video_set_callbacks method as parameters.

Comment: Problem is my codes working very good in main form but when I want to create a new component with my codes in main form, I have this problem. Problem is that libvlc_video_set_callbacks function cannot callback my static function in a component unit but in the main form unit he can callback.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a delphi XE2 bug, they accept that problem as bug 
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=101180

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).